# How to update column in AWS Athena Table

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have a table in Athena with the following columns.

```
Describe my_table
```

> row_id
>   icd9_code
>                                                      linksto

The column `icd9_code` is empty with `int`data type. I want to insert some integer values to the column `icd9_code` of my table named `my_table`.

Those integer values are stored in an excel sheet in my local pc. Does AWS athena provide some way to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon Athena is primarily designed to run SQL queries across data stored in Amazon S3. It is not able to access data stored in Microsoft Excel files, nor is it able to access files stored on your computer.

To update a particular column of data for existing rows of data, you would need to **modify the files in Amazon S3 that contain those rows of data**.